# How pass path value from child to Parent

Tags: reactjs

I am making a MERN  crud app where I want to pass the _id of the record from my displayRecord.js component to app.js( inside the Route path = {} ) to update my data onclick on update button

### Part of the code sort of goes like this

### displayRecord.js

```
         .....
          <td>
            <li>
              <Link to={`/${record._id}`}>
              <button className='updateRecordBtn' onClick={()=>updateRecord(record._id)}>UPDATE</button>
              </Link>
            </li>
          </td>
         ......
```

I need to capture that and pass it to the path as follows in app.js

```
   <Router>
    <Routes>
      <Route path={`/${record._id}`} element={<UpdateRecord />} />
      <Route path='/' element={<Home/>} />
    </Routes>
  </Router>
```

How to make that  {record._id} available in app.js. it is currently showing  record._id not defined

Suggestions and possible solutions are appreciated

I need to capture that and pass it to the path as follows in app.js

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect usage, take a look at the official docs here, and feel free to return if you need more help.

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial

Comment: Very helpful...thanks for this reference manual

Comment: I'd rather you know what your doing is not how to do it, then go research how to actually do it instead of me just writing the code for you, or explaining it hoping you would understand my wording.

Comment: Sure !! I will do the necessary research !! Thanks for your feedback.   Btw there are so many content on the net...sometimes I get confused  which approach to follow...